# SharePoint online, external cloud storage for images and videos

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, remote-blob-storage, storage, blob

I am implementing a sharepoint online and have an issue with images and videos.  Basically, there are more than 30Gb of videos and images being generated every week and we need to keep them easily accessible in our sharepoint online (using also tagging and metadata for easier access and search)

I want to know what other solutions there might be for storage on the cloud for this volume of data and linking to SharePoint Online.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check on using OneDrive. According to the official doc [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/onedrive-for-business-service-description)
1 TB per user for subscriptions with fewer than 5 users. For subscriptions with 5 or more users, Microsoft will initially provide 1 TB per user, which admins can increase to up to 5 TB per user.

It is closely connected to SharePoint Online as a important component in O365. You can check [this introduction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/set-up-file-storage-and-sharing?view=o365-worldwide)

The only drawback is that metadata for now is not supported in OneDrive. You will need to use folders to handle your videos and images.